# How to obtain the Eternal Conqueror of The Fissure of Woe title in GW?

Tags: guild-wars

My question is should we do the Fissure of Woe in Hard Mode or Normal Mode in enough to obtain the title of Eternal Conqueror of The Fissure of Woe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to do it on hard mode in order to get the Fissure of Woe statue.  In fact, I would recommend doing it on normal to keep things simple.